# Default directory change by command line

Tags: python, windows, powershell, automation, installation-path

Recently I had a need to change the installation directory of a program, and I wanted to know how to execute such a function via PowerShell, Python, or any other.

This would be for Windows, for example, when we install via UI it offers us a default installation directory, as in the example below with 7-Zip.

[image: Img1]

Through the UI we can freely change this directory, but I wanted to know how you can do the same operation from the command line, to change it to something like the example below.

[image: Img2]

This would be very useful in automation scripts, especially when working with high volumes of machines.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: There is no generic way to do this, it depends on the kind of setup program that is being used. You have to either look up the documentation for the specific software or try to call the setup with `/?` which in some cases shows you the available options.

Comment: You could also try to use a symbolic link to change the actual place where files are installed, but careful there, as the program once installed might look for the files in the preprogrammed specified directory and not in your symbolic location. as Zett mentioned this will depend on the specific setup files

Comment: Thanks @zett42, really, I had to resort to the documentation for the program in question, and I'm making progress. In fact, my original idea was to find a generic way to do the process, but as you yourself pointed out, apparently this doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @arana, I was thinking of going this route but some issues can occur so I will take the advice to read and understand the documentation for that particular software, to understand how it works and how to move forward with the project.

Note: The software is not 7-zip.

Answer (score 0):

According to 7zip documentation, to install it in a silent mode you can :

***For exe installer:*** Use the "/S" parameter to do a silent installation and the /D="C:\Program Files\7-Zip" parameter to specify the "output directory". These options are case-sensitive.

***For msi installer:*** Use the /q INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\7-Zip" parameters.

In the second case it's quite a standard for Windows.

Comment: Wow!
Thanks a lot @JPBlancName, but 7-Zip was just used as an example, what I wanted was a generic way to do this kind of automation, but as mentioned above, not all software follows a pattern so I'll read the documentation to solve this specific problem.
Thank you very much for your time.